# Изменение размера шрифта в cmd через python

Tags: python, cmd, шрифты

Возможно ли указать размер шрифта в cmd через print ?

Comment: Насколько я знаю, питон не имеет отношения к графическим настройкам cmd

Comment: А Вы пробовали ответ искать на [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52336257/)?